# Entering python code in textarea using sendkey, but not working. Any solution?(selenium Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I set string in which i stored the python code and pass this string to using sendkey. But the code got unstructured and extra spaces and words got entered in the code.

**Below is the code**:

```
//Defining the string
 String code = "# Python program to display the Fibonacci sequence\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "def recur_fibo(n):\n" + 
                "   if n <= 1:\n" + 
                "       return n\n" + 
                "   else:\n" + 
                "       return(recur_fibo(n-1) + recur_fibo(n-2))\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "nterms = 10\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "# check if the number of terms is valid\n" + 
                "if nterms <= 0:\n" + 
                "   print(\"Plese enter a positive integer\")\n" + 
                "else:\n" + 
                "   print(\"Fibonacci sequence:\")\n" + 
                "   for i in range(nterms):\n" + 
                "       print(recur_fibo(i))";
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-test/div[1]/section/div/ace-editor/div[2]/div"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(elem).click().perform();
        WebElement elem1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-test/div[1]/section/div/ace-editor/div[2]/div/div[3]"));
        Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
//Selected all the content of the editor
        actions1.moveToElement(elem1).click().click().click().click();
//Entering the code
        actions1.moveToElement(elem1).sendKeys(code).perform();
```

**The code in Editor entered as shown in below screenshot**:[click to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMVtC.png)

**The code in editor should be like below**:

```
# Python program to display the Fibonacci sequence

def recur_fibo(n):
   if n <= 1:
       return n
   else:
       return(recur_fibo(n-1) + recur_fibo(n-2))

nterms = 10

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <= 0:
   print("Plese enter a positive integer")
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   for i in range(nterms):
       print(recur_fibo(i))
```

In python spacing and indentation is very important so the code entered in editor throw error on compilation.
Is there any way to send whole code as it's in the editor?

Comment: Its working fine tried with sample textarea tag using selenium.Refer [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stNLM.png).Kindly post your html dom code or site url in which you are facing the issue

Comment: @DecodeD : Are you using 'Ace Editor'?

Comment: @Dilip Meghwal : yes my application use Ace Editor

Comment: @Mohamed Sulaimaan Sheriff : You can try on Ideone.com. It doesn't work.

Comment: Your XPath locators definitely need to be improved. Verify elem1. Also, actions1.moveToElement(elem1).click().click().click().click() look very suspicious.  Another point: why do you create two Actions objects? You most probably need only one.

Comment: @Vitaliis : Can you please suggest me the improvement for xpath? and about 4 times click(), i wanted to perform select all operation in the editor so nothing else was working then i tried this way.

Comment: If its not confidential, can you please share the URL of the website you are using.

Comment: I will need to see you html code first. Then I can help with XPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

The editor name to be found by searching the keyword "ace.edit" in the javaScript file.

```
Eg. var editor = ace.edit("editor_demo) // 'editor_demo' is the id of the element Eg. <div id = 'editor_demo'></div>
```

With help of 'editor' variable we can set the editor text by using Selenium JavascriptExecutor.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("editor.setValue(arguments[0])", "Desired String that we want to set to the editor");
```

Complete program by using https://ace.c9.io/ website.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://ace.c9.io/");
    String code = "print('Hello World')";
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ace_editor_demo\"]")));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("editor.setValue(arguments[0])", code);
```

If you are not able to identify the Ace Editor name then use below approach.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String code = "var temp = 'Hello World'";
    driver.get("https://example.com/AuthenticateKey?id=ValidAuthKey");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//app-landing-page//button[@type='submit']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-landing-page//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//app-authenticate//input[@placeholder='Enter full name']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-authenticate//input[@placeholder='Enter full name']")).sendKeys("Test Automation");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-authenticate//input[@placeholder='Enter email address']")).sendKeys("---Your email ID---");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-authenticate//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//app-test-instructions//button[contains(text(), 'Start Test')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//app-test-instructions//button[contains(text(), 'Start Test')]")).click();;
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='sectionInstModal']//a[contains(text(), 'Start Section')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sectionInstModal']//a[contains(text(), 'Start Section')]")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='_sectionTime']")));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String jsQuery = "var el = document.querySelector('#code-fix-h > div > ace-editor');ace.edit(el).setValue(arguments[0]);";
    js.executeScript(jsQuery, code);
```

Comment: @DecodeD : Finally got the solution. You have to execute below code with javaScript executor. You can try this with chrome developer console. Note : Don't forget to define code variable.'var el = document.querySelector("#code-fix-h > div > ace-editor");ace.edit(el).setValue(code);'

Comment: Can you share the code, i never used javascript executor before so bit confused. I didn't find ace.edit() in HTML DOM. I'm using selenium with Java, Are you using C#?

Comment: @DecodeD : Code added for your problem in answer and its working fine. Just replace valid auth key in URL, enter valid email id and run the script. Note : Remove the auth key from your first comment URL, if you are having premium account that might cost you some amount if someone use that.