# How to locate and type into SimpleMde RichText editor with CodeceptJs

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeceptjs

I am trying to type into a RichText editor using CodeceptJs and Selenium but so far the only way I'm able to do this is by **clicking the previous input field on the page and tabbing from it to the RichText editor and once there I then add my text simulating a keyboard interaction**.However, I feel there may be a better way to do this and also to locate the editor to see if it's displayed on the screen.

I have tried grabbing both the textarea and the span tags that I see when inspecting the page, but none of them would work. I've also gone through the length of trying to **use a javascript executor to remove the display none property on the hidden textarea** that seems to accompany that field and I can type there but still not on the textarea inside the text editor. I've also checked to see if the editor would perhaps be inside a frame that I would need to switch to but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Any help much appreciated please.

```
async checkAllElementsAreDisplayed() {
    await I.seeElement(this.titleInput)
    await I.seeElement(this.summaryInput)

    await I.executeScript(function() {
        const doc = document.evaluate('//div[3]/div[1]/textarea', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        doc.style.display='inline';
        doc.click()
    });

    await I.click(this.summaryInput)
    await I.pressKey("Tab");
    await I.pressKey("a");

    I.fillField(this.textArea, "my text" )
    await I.saveScreenshot('textarea.png', true)


    await I.seeElement(this.textArea)
    await I.seeElement(this.userInput)
    await I.seeElement(this.secretInput)
    await I.seeElement(this.saveButton)
}
```

PS: The RichText editor comes as a React component from `import * as SimpleMDE from "easymde";`

```
<div className="container container-narrow">
    <SimpleMDE
    className={""}
    value={this.state.textValue}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/> </div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please update the question with code editor name or the URL for reference. You might get some help from this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718405/entering-python-code-in-textarea-using-sendkey-but-not-working-any-solutions/63740285#63740285)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. Sorry, do you mean the name for the component that originates the editor? It's a React component that comes from here ```import * as SimpleMDE from "easymde";```

Comment: In your HTML code it seems its codeMirror editor. Once you find the editor try to set the text using JavaScript Executor.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is being harder than I'd expect. Tried several different things but it's still not working I'm afraid.

Comment: ```await I.executeScript(function() {
            const doc = document.evaluate(this.tarea, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
            doc.textContent='text'
            doc.click()
        });```

Comment: This gives me a null error

Comment: ```await I.seeElement(this.editor)
        await I.wait(5)
        await I.fillField(this.tarea, "test")```

Comment: And this gives me an element not interactable

Comment: Can you try to execute plain javascript statement `document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-code')[0].textContent = "My Text"`

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid ```await I.executeScript(function() {
            const doc = document.evaluate('//div[3]/div[1]/textarea', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
            doc.style.display='inline';
            doc.click()

            document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-code')[0].textContent = "My Text"
        });``` won't type and if I put the document.getElements piece outside this part I get a document doesn't exist error.